# Update single table information from multiple screens not depending on Primary Key?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, logic, structure

I have a table that contains job licenses information, only License Id, License Name. e.g. Id1 - License 1, Id2 - License 2 etc.

Now, I have a table called Jobs that contains job information with date and license No for License 1 and License 2 e.g.

`JobId`, `JobName`, `JobType`, `License1Date`, `License1No`, `License2Date`, `License2No` etc.

I have 3rd Screen which I am using to follow-up for `License1` and `License2`. As I receive the `License1` I update the `License1` Information which is in Jobs table and likewise for `License2`.

Currently, I am using manual way to update Jobs table. Following is my code:

```
public ActionResult Received(int LicenseId, string Date, string License)
{   
    // LicenseId is the Primary Key in License Tables.

    if (LicenseId == 1)
    {
        // Update License 1 Information of Jobs Table
    }
    else if(LicenseId == 2)
    {
        // Update License 2 Information of Jobs Table
    }
}
```

This one is working fine. But the problem is LicenseId is the key of License table. If the user puts `Id1` is `License2` and `Id2` is `License1` then it's going to be a problem.

In this case, if the user receives license 2, it will update the license 1 information of Jobs table since manually I have configured Id 1 means Update license 1 information of Job Table. How can I make it dynamic?

Update: Let me change scenario to simplify., I have one table saving Licenses and second table saving Jobs and 3rd Table is the bridge tavle saving Licens Id and Job Id. Now, I have Details Screen, with 3 Labels. I want to fill first label if licence is license 1 , second if license 2 and third if license 3. In license table, license 1 could be on 1,2 or 3. I can’t say if Id is 1 then fill first label. I know I should loop through. Suppose, I don’t want to then how can I achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be useful? You can also concatenate currentLicense with "No" and "Date", etc.

```
public ActionResult Received(int LicenseId, string Date, string License)
{   
   string currentLicense = string.Concat("License", LicenseId);
   //update for currentLicense
}
```

Comment: it’s an example. In reality, license names are different.

Comment: @AshirK. If names are not similiar, are they random? What about using only license id/number?

Comment: Yes names are different. e.g. Ministry of Health License, Ministry of Foreign Affairs License

Answer (score 0):

In your table structure, `Jobs` is having direct fields for `licenseIds`. So in future when you have new `licenseId` then you need to alter `Jobs` table to add more Fields for `licenseId`

And your question, shows that one `job` can have multiple `licenseId`

If possible to change table structure, I suggest that `Jobs` table should be separate table and you need to have a junction table for `License` and `Job`.

**Example**

*Jobs Table columns*
`Id`, `JobName`, `JobType`……

*LicenseJobs (junction Table) columns*

`JobId`, `LicenseId`, `LicenseDate`

This way you dont have to worry about licenseId and just call database update for licenseId & JobId.

After this, you need to pass JobId too to database, so Action needs modification

```
public ActionResult Received(int jobId, int LicenseId, string Date, string License)
{   
}
```

**Edit** - -

In your new scenario, it shows that your UI logic is dependent on text “License1” or “License2”. So both Id and Text has to be Unique in License table.
So, you need to have `Enum` or `string` contants in your code that will be same as `LicenseName` in `Licenses` table. So then you can always query `Licenses` table first to get *Id of license* and then fetch/update other details according to that `Id`.

Comment: You are correct it should be like this. But still somewhere its going to be same problem to identify e.g. on details I have a heading: MOFA license then shoud details for MOFA license. I hope you are getting ny point.

Comment: On followUp screen (screen 3) when you got update for license1, how you know which Job to update? If you have multiple jobs with same license id? @AshirK.

Comment: Let me change scenario to simplify., I have one table saving Licenses and second table saving Jobs and 3rd Table is the bridge tavle saving Licens Id and Job Id.  Now, I have Details Screen, with 3 Labels. I want to fill first label if licence is license 1 , second if license 2 and third if license 3. In license table, license 1 could be on 1,2 or 3. I can’t say if Id is 1 then fill first label. I know I should loop through. Suppose, I don’t want to then how can I achieve it.

Comment: Logic depending on Text rather than id. See edited answer. @AshirK.

Comment: If still something not clear, put images of your UI screens and exact table design + some more code